# Erro ao customizar um menu usando actionLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

**Eu estava utilizando para customizar meus itens do menu o atributo actionLayout mas, ocorreu o seguinte erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Layout menu_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    style="@android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:textSize="6pt"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: Não está funcionando? Sua `Activity` herda de ´ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Minha activit herda de Activity... eu tentei herdar de ActionBarActivity mas não estou conseguindo..

Comment: Está usando o `appcompat`? O `ActionBarActivity` é da biblioteca do `app compat`.

Comment: consegui importar mas da erro.. eu estou usando na minha activity tabs pra poder selecionar os fragments isso pode dar erro? pois quando eu estava herdando de Activity não dava erro, somente não aparecia o menu...

Comment: eu já encontrei o erro.. era no android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item" não posso utilizar um menucustomizado

Comment: Pode sim, basta adicionar um atributo igual sem o prefixo `android:`.

Comment: eu adicionei o item com app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item" mas da erro no xml não compila

Comment: Não faz sentido, qual erro ele gera?

Comment: vou tirar print pra você ver... eu tmb procurei em muitos foruns e não vi logica pra esse erro.^^

Comment: @PedroRangel percebi que você editou toda a sua pergunta anterior para outra. Como é uma nova dúvida, o ideal seria que você criasse uma nova e não editasse essa, já que a dúvida anterior pode ser dúvida de outros usuários, além dos comentários aqui terem ficado fora do contexto com essa edição.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues e pq quando fiz uma pergunta, sem querer eu coloquei pra conceder recompensa... e já tinha resolvida... já que não é possível voltar os pontos, eu não quis perder eles e fiz uma outra pergunta^^

Comment: Pedro, eu acho que não perde quando o tempo expira, seria legal ver no FAQ a regra. Mas como o @PauloRodrigues disse, é melhor criar uma nova pergunta, porque tudo que foi escrito antes perdeu o sentido.

Comment: blz...@Wakim e @PauloRodrigues obrigado pela dica de vocês, desculpa qualquer coisa^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Já consegui resolver depois de muito penar e com ajuda do @Wakim:**

**Configuracao xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" > 

    <item
        android:id="@+id/acaoAdicionar"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/adicionar"

        />

</menu>
```

**Código na activity:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_tefone, menu);
        configureActionLayout(menu);
    }

public void configureActionLayout(Menu menu) {// Menu Customizado

        for (int i = 0, c = menu.size(); i < c; ++i) {

            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            TextView actionLayout = (TextView) item.getActionView();
            actionLayout.setText(item.getTitle());
            actionLayout.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    item.getIcon(), null, null, null);
            actionLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```